# How does the `acpi` command calculate the battery life when `charge_now` and other files are not present?

Tags: power-management, acpi, battery

I am writing a C program that calculates the remaining battery life or charge time, depending on if the battery is charging. The way I do this is by reading some files in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0`. To calculate the remaining battery life:

```
battery life = charge_now / current_now
```

To calculate the charge time:

```
charge time = (charge_full - charge_now) / current_now
```

The two formulas above yield the exact same results as the output of the `acpi` command. However, I noticed that sometimes, for some reason, the files `charge_now`, `charge_full`, and `current_now` are not present in the directory, but other files such as `capacity` and `status` still are. When this happens, I am unable to calculate the battery life or the charge time. But `acpi` is still able to calculate it. Why do these files sometimes disappear and how is `acpi` still able to calculate the battery life and charge time when that happens?

Comment: `acpi` is open source. Download the source, unpack the source, read the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As waltinator said in the comments, this is best answered by reading the source code of the `acpi` command. But where can it be found?

On Debian and related distributions, you can query for "which package owns this command?" with e.g.

```
dpkg-query -S /usr/bin/acpi
acpi: /usr/bin/acpi
```

Once you know the package name, you can find the name of the corresponding source code package and usually the URL of the project it came from:

```
apt info acpi
[...]
Homepage: http://sourceforge.net/projects/acpiclient
[...]
```

So, the project name is `acpiclient` and it's on Sourceforge.
Clicking on the `Code` tab on the project webpage allows us to browse its Git repository: https://sourceforge.net/p/acpiclient/code/

The main header file for the command, [acpi.h](https://sourceforge.net/p/acpiclient/code/ci/master/tree/acpi.h#l64), might give a good overview of the structure of the program. On line 64, we find the prototype for the `print_battery_information()` function, which sounds promising...

..and that function can be found starting at [line 251 of file `acpi.c`](https://sourceforge.net/p/acpiclient/code/ci/master/tree/acpi.c#l251).

It parses a number of fields, each named to match the virtual files that may be available at `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0` (as you can verify by a more thorough read through the code). It appears that the information on remaining battery capacity can be found from multiple files:

- `remaining capacity` (in milliamp-hours)
- or `charge_now` (in microamp-hours)
- or `energy_now` (in microwatt-hours).

Likewise, the rate of power consumption can be found as:

- `present rate` (in milliamps)
- `current_now` (in microamps)
- `power_now` (in microwatts)

Using any of these, the remaining runtime on battery (at the current consumption level) can be calculated, after applying any appropriate unit conversions.